# Systemd service without external display - Process raises an exception ansd exits

Tags: ssh, systemd, x11

I am trying to run an app as a systemd service. An example service file is given as follows.

```
[Unit]
Description = Custom APP 
Wants = network.target
After = syslog.target network-online.target graphical.target
StartLimitIntervalSec = 0

[Service]
User = 
Type = simple
Environment = 
WorkingDirectory = 
ExecStart = 
Restart = always
RestartSec = 60
KillMode = control-group

[Install]
WantedBy = graphical.target
```

I run the service via ssh. OS is ubuntu 18.04.
The service and the process works as expected if an external display is connected to the device and I ssh on the device after the machine has been logged in once over GUI for all cases.

But when I reboot the device and remove the external display and and just login via ssh i.e without GUI based login, these things happen

- If I am running the app as a simple process from the commandline, it works as expected.
- If I try to run the app as a systemd service, it exits after raising exception.
- If I just login once via GUI and don't reboot the device, the service works even if I remove the external display.

I am at a loss as to why this is happening.

**Edit**

- Exception raised is - terminate called without an active exception
- It's a C++ gstreamer based streaming application.

Comment: I feel it is somehow related to the loading of x11 server.

Comment: There's not enough information here to really address your question.  What does the app do?  And, exactly what exception is raised?  I'd suggest editing your question, and copy/paste the exact error message into the question.